# aws amplify re-configuration, delete an existing config and create a new

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify-cli

I want to delete an already existing amplify configuration where i used api gateway and lambda function and dynamodb. Can i delete everything and create everything as a new configuration.
How to do it.?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
amplify delete
amplify init
amplify <resource> add
```

etc.

Comment: will that create any error in back-end because my production is up and running. but my back-end having errors so i think of deleting it.

Comment: "delete" deprovisions cloud resources. So does "amplify remove <env>", but is use if you have multiple environments running. It would be good to know what errors you're getting?